# peewee: How to add where clause to any select?

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I have models like this:

```
class AbstractBaseModel(peewee.Model):
    uuid = peewee.UUIDField(default=uuid4)
    is_active = peewee.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_deleted = peewee.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = peewee.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    deleted_at = peewee.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        indexes = (
            (('is_active', 'is_deleted'), False),
        )
```

I would like to:

1. (as default) able to select rows with `is_active == True` and `is_deleted == False`

or

2. select all rows but just skipping `is_active` and `is_deleted` flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to extend great [coleifer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54919057/320104) answer.**

For joins and more complicates queries we can use PeeWee [CTE](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#common-table-expressions) feature as follows:

```
class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    is_deleted = peewee.BooleanField(default=False, index=True)

    @classmethod
    def visible_where_clause(cls):
        return cls.is_deleted == False

    @classmethod
    def visible(cls):
        return cls.select().where(cls.visible_where_clause())

    @classmethod
    def cte(cls, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = 'CTE_{}'.format(cls.__name__)
        return cls.visible().cte(name)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class User(BaseModel):
    username = peewee.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = peewee.BooleanField(default=True, index=True)

    @classmethod
    def visible_where_clause(cls):
        return (
            (super().visible_where_clause()) & (cls.is_active == True)
        )

UserCTE = User.cte()


class Post(BaseModel):
    status = peewee.IntegerField()  # 1=live, 2=draft, 3=deleted, e.g.
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User)
    title = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)

    @classmethod
    def visible_where_clause(cls):
        return (
                (super().visible_where_clause()) & (cls.status == 1)
        )

PostCTE = Post.cte()
```

Then when we want only active posts for active users we can do something like this:

```
posts = (
    Post
    .visible()
    .select(Post.title)
    .join(UserCTE, on=Post.user == UserCTE.c.id)
    .with_cte(UserCTE)
)
for post in posts:
    print(post.title)
```

**REMEMBER**

The for `CTE` object you must reference by adding `.c.<column_name>` and add this `cte` at end of your query by adding `.with_cte(<list of all used CTEs>)`

Comment: Congratulations on learning about CTE. This answer certainly muddies the waters and makes it rather confusing for anyone who arrives here via Google. Instead of answering your actual question, you've talked about rather advanced features and written lots of lines of useless stuff for someone to have to wade through to get to the actual answer.

Comment: @coleifer so can You extend your answer to provide more flexible solution? How to create something like View or Proxy to model when you want to use it in joins ?

Answer (score 2):

It is just Python... add a helper method to your model class. For example, if I have a `Post` class for blog posts, I might write:

```
class Post(Model):
    status = IntegerField()  # 1=live, 2=draft, 3=deleted, e.g.

    @classmethod
    def visible(cls):
        return cls.select().where(cls.status == 1)
```

Then, I might have a list-view of all published posts:

```
@app.route('/')
def post_index():
    query = Post.visible().order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())
    return render_template('post_index.html', query=query)
```

Comment: do you have any idea how to apply this to joins?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that is not peculiar to peewee.

Suppose your (unnamed) table above is "thing", so essentially your model is good at queries like `select * from thing`.

Now define a related view that picks out certain things, picks out your favorite subset of rows:

```
sqlite> create view thing_v  as
   ...>   select uuid, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at
   ...>   from thing
   ...>   where is_active == True and is_deleted == False;
```

Point your model at *that* relation, which happens to be a view (a named query) rather than a table.